# PHP/JSOn: why is https url json-encoded as null?

Tags: php, mysql, json, string, url

I have an online MySQL where a table has a column containing an https URL which is stored as `varchar(255)`. For example, here's a screenshot from phpMyAdmin:

[image]

The strange thing which is actually happens, is that when I get the data from MySQL through PHP and I encode them into JSON (so that to be delivered to an iOS app) then the caption is always `null`. Here's my code:

```
public function fieldInfoByFishID($fish_id){
    $sql = mysqli_query($this->config->dbConn,"SELECT * FROM  ".$this->config->table_fields." WHERE id_fish='".$fish_id."'");
    $v = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $tmp = array(
        'id'=>$v['id'],
        'id_fish'=>$v['id_fish'],
        'description_info'=>utf8_encode($v['description_info']),
        'recognition_info'=>utf8_encode($v['recognition_info']),
        'place_info'=>utf8_encode($v['place_info']),
        'fishing_method'=>$v['fishing_method'],
        'buy_period'=>$v['buy_period'],
        'caption'=>$v['caption'],
        'life_method'=>utf8_encode($v['life_method']),
        'exploitation_status'=>$v['exploitation_status']
    );
    return $tmp;
}
```

The code looks correct to me but I don't know why that column is not fetched. Is there a particular attention I have to pay in order to get the url correctly? I thought it was just a simple string.

Here's an example:

[image]

Obviously, if I tr to exec the sql query in phpMyAdmin console, it all works fine.
Thank you all.

Comment: Can you post a sample output array?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde just added, click on the image!

Comment: check that you don't have spaces in the `caption` field, it might be `'caption '` maybe?

Comment: @AlonEitan Holy s***!!! You're totally right. There was a damned white space after `caption` in the column name...I wonder why phpMyAdmin let me do it or did not delete it when I was creating the table...

Comment: @LoryLory First, i'm glad I was able to assist. Second, you can put spaces in the column name (AFAIK) so that's why PHPmyadmin allowed it

Comment: If you want to post Ill mark it as the answer!

Comment: Slightly unrelated, `mysqli_fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` has its own method, you can just do `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` if you want.

Comment: That's fine, too easy for the rep. ;) Thanks though